# "Резиновый" двумерный массив, который подстроится под условия

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, python-3.x

Я уже который день бьюсь с алгоритмом, который сама придумала, но не могу его реализовать, звучит он так: Есть кол-во картинок `illust`, знаем что максимально строк двумерного массива `post` может быть не более `max_post`, но и не меньше `min_post`. А элементов в этих строках не более 7, к тому же, количество элементов всегда рандомно от 2 до 7.

Цель такая, чтобы заполнить двумерный массив всеми картинками, а двумерный массив подстроился под условия, которые я сказала. Т.е. в итоге, элементы в строках, как бы, должны растянуться (Вот где у меня сейчас по 7 элементов, они могли бы стать двумя строками по 4 и 3 элемента, тогда бы до `min_post` дошло бы). Вот не могу додумать как это сделать...

Как можно оптимизировать/переписать/дописать это ?

```
illust = 108 # All pictures
a = [] # array
elemets = 0 #element in array
illust_number = 1 #the current number of images
post = 0 # line in array
max_post = 40
min_post = 30


    while elemets < illust:
        if illust_number < illust:
            while illust_number < illust:
                if illust_number < illust:
                    elemets = random.randint(2, 7)
                    if illust_number + elemets <= illust:
                        a.append([])
                        for c in range(elemets):
                            a[post].append(illust_number)
                            illust_number += 1
                    else:
                        elemets = random.randint(1, illust - illust_number)
                        a.append([])
                        for c in range(elemets):
                            a[post].append(illust_number)
                            illust_number += 1
                else:
                    break
                post += 1
        else:
            break
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[12, 13]
[14, 15, 16, 17]
[18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
[23, 24, 25]
[26, 27, 28]
[29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
[35, 36]
[37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43]
[44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
[51, 52, 53, 54]
[55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61]
[62, 63, 64, 65, 66]
[67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73]
[74, 75]
[76, 77]
[78, 79, 80, 81, 82]
[83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88]
[89, 90, 91]
[92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98]
[99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105]
[106, 107]
```

Comment: Если расположить по 3 картинке в ряд, без рандома, то граничные условия выполнятся 108 // 3 == 36

Comment: @Iliaw495Nikitin, да, вот только изображений всегда может быть по разному, не только 108, а допустим: 40 или 200

Comment: @MarieRose напишите функцию которая будет делить список, и возвращать генератор, потом добавляйте в основной список результат.

Comment: @MarieRose А не могли бы вы немного пояснить вопрос, я не понимаю что Вы имеете ввиду под строками? Это кол-во массивов? Могли бы Вы привести пример вывода, который бы Вас устроил? Или Вывод, который Вы предоставили Вас устраивает, вопрос в оптимизации кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы разместить `npictures` картинок в `nrows_min..nrows_max` строк и `ncols_min..ncols_max` столбцов:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

ncols = npictures // nrows_min if npictures < nrows_min * ncols_max else ncols_max
print(*zip_longest(*[iter(range(1, npictures + 1))]*ncols), sep='\n')
```

где:

```
npictures = 108  # количество картинок
nrows_max = 40   # максимальное количество строк
nrows_min = 20   # минимальное количество строк
ncols_max = 7    # максимальное количество столбцов
ncols_min = 2    # минимальное количество столбцов

assert nrows_min * ncols_min <= npictures <= nrows_max * ncols_max
assert nrows_min < nrows_max
```

Пример:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
(16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
(21, 22, 23, 24, 25)
(26, 27, 28, 29, 30)
(31, 32, 33, 34, 35)
(36, 37, 38, 39, 40)
(41, 42, 43, 44, 45)
(46, 47, 48, 49, 50)
(51, 52, 53, 54, 55)
(56, 57, 58, 59, 60)
(61, 62, 63, 64, 65)
(66, 67, 68, 69, 70)
(71, 72, 73, 74, 75)
(76, 77, 78, 79, 80)
(81, 82, 83, 84, 85)
(86, 87, 88, 89, 90)
(91, 92, 93, 94, 95)
(96, 97, 98, 99, 100)
(101, 102, 103, 104, 105)
(106, 107, 108, None, None)
```

*Чтобы выполнить требование `ncols_min`, можно по одному элементу с предыдущих строк собирать (возможно более одного раза, если строк мало) пока не наберётся как минимум `ncols_min` элементов.*

Чтобы этот алгоритм при допустимом вводе не сделал бы предыдущие строчки слишком узкими, можно выбирать наибольшее возможное `ncols`:

```
from math import ceil

ncols = min(ceil(npictures / nrows_min), ncols_max)
```

Чтобы можно было строчки редактировать их можно как списки представлять:

```
rows = list(map(list, zip_longest(*[iter(range(1, npictures + 1))]*ncols)))
while rows[-1][-1] is None: # remove trailing None values
    rows[-1].pop()
```

В этом случае количество строк может получиться меньше `nrows_min`, поэтому необходимо прибавить недостающие строки:

```
rows += [[] for _ in range(nrows_min - len(rows))]  # len(rows) >= nrows_min
```

Тогда вышеописанный алгоритм (выделен *курсивом*), который добавляет элементы в короткие строки (чтобы до `ncols_min` каждую строчку дополнить):

```
for i in range(len(rows)-1, -1, -1):
    while len(rows[i]) < ncols_min:
        for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):
            if len(rows[j]) > ncols_min:
                rows[i].append(rows[j].pop())
                if len(rows[i]) == ncols_min:
                    break
            elif j == 0:
                raise ValueError("impossible constraints")

assert nrows_min <= len(rows) <= nrows_max
assert all(ncols_min <= len(row) <= ncols_max for row in rows)
```

В этом случае результат:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
 [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
 [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
 [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
 [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36],
 [37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42],
 [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48],
 [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
 [55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60],
 [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66],
 [67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72],
 [73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78],
 [79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84],
 [85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90],
 [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96],
 [97, 98, 99, 100],
 [103, 104, 105, 106],
 [107, 101],
 [108, 102]]
```

О том [как `zip(*[iterator]*n)` идиома работает, см. по ссылкам в ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/377884/23044).