# Разбить строку на N символов (подстрок одинаковой длины) и занести в массив

Tags: python, массивы, строки

Имеется строка из X символов, необходимо разбить её на N символов и забить значения по переменным, если в конечном значении отсеченная часть меньше, чем N, то мы её удаляем.
На примере:
Имеется строка London_is_the_capital_of_great_Britain. Её необходимо разбить на группы по 6 символов и каждую группу внести в отдельную строчную переменную (или в массив).

```
s='London_is_the_capital_of_great_Britain'
[s[x:x+6] for x in range (0, len(s), 6)]
['London', '_is_th', 'e_capi', 'tal_of', '_great', '_Brita', 'in']
```

Здесь видно, что последняя группа содержит менее 6 символов, значит мы ее не должны заносить в отдельную переменную, а просто отсечь.

Comment: `[s[x:x+6] for x in range (0, len(s) - len(s) % 6, 6)]`

Comment: @slippyk По идее делать "- len(s) % 6" нет смысла

Comment: @vitidev что за идея?

Comment: @slippyk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В [itertools-recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) приведен пример реализации функции `grouper`, которая принимает на вход итерируемый объект и число, обозначающее размер последовательностей, на которые будет разбит исходный объект. В основе функции лежит [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) - может быть заменена на встроенный `zip` (комментарий [jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717303/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-n-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2/717338?noredirect=1#comment1078273_717338)).

```
def grouper(iterable, n):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip(*args)

s = 'London_is_the_capital_of_great_Britain'
l = [''.join(i) for i in grouper(s, 6)]
print(l)

['London', '_is_th', 'e_capi', 'tal_of', '_great', '_Brita']
```

Comment: чтобы отбросить некратную часть, можно zip вместо zip_longest использовать.

Comment: да, это понятно, но потом то следует добавить эти группы в отдельные переменные

Comment: В чём проблема? И какой в этом смысл?

Comment: смысл в том, чтобы потом перемешивать эти группы по заданному алгоритму (шифр перестановки)

Comment: @Xendler, в чем суть проблемы? Если число групп по `N` символов известно, то можно и распаковать полученный список в отдельные переменные. Но, скорее всего, это не лучший выход. Можно создать новый список с перемешанным по вашему алгоритму порядком. Если важно соответствие каждой из групп какому-то имени, то сразу создавать словарь.

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы выбросить группу, которая меньше по длине, в конце списка:

```
n = 6    
chunks = [s[i - n:i] for i in range(n, len(s) + 1, n)]
```

Ещё (из [@slippyk комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717303/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-n-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-python#comment1078085_717303)):

```
chunks = [s[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(s) - (len(s) % n), n)]
```

Более наглядно предел для `i` можно записать как: `n * (len(s) // n)`— выражение делает длину `s` как будто кратной `n`.

Если список не нужен:

```
chunks = map(''.join, zip(*[iter(s)] * n))
```

Первый вариант более читаем. Последний вариант работает не только для последовательностей. `zip()` автоматически не кратный остаток выкидывает. Вот [объяснение, что `zip(*[iterator]*n) делает`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/377884/23044).

Пример:

```
>>> s = 'London_is_the_capital_of_great_Britain'
>>> print(*map(''.join, zip(*[iter(s)] * 6)), sep=' | ')
London | _is_th | e_capi | tal_of | _great | _Brita
```

Answer (score 2):

такой вариант работает и в python2 и в python3:

```
import re
s = 'London_is_the_capital_of_great_Britain'
n = 6
print(re.findall('.{%s}' % n, s))
```

результат:

```
['London', '_is_th', 'e_capi', 'tal_of', '_great', '_Brita']
```

Answer (score 0):

[aleksandr-barakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/aleksandr-barakin)

Спасибо! Интересный и лаконичный способ.

Но можно немножко улучшить регулярку:

```
print(re.findall('(.{%s}|.+$)' % n, s))
```

тогда будет выдаваться и последняя неполная часть:

```
['London', '_is_th', 'e_capi', 'tal_of', '_great', '_Brita', 'in']
```

Comment: В вопросе специально упомянуто, что выдавать неполный хвостик не нужно.

Comment: Регулярку в вашем решении можно ещё упростить: `re.findall(f'.{{1,{n}}}', s)`.