# Как в Python разбить строку по 4 символа и сохранить эти "четвёрки" в списке?

Tags: python

То есть есть например строка: "У Маши рыжая корова" и надо разбить строку по 4 символа: "У Ма", "ши е", "сть ", "рыжа", "я ко", "рова". И всё это надо сохранить в списке, например `spisok = ["У Ма", "ши е", "сть ", "рыжа", "я ко", "рова"]`. И, пожалуйста. с объяснениями, по возможности. Спасибо!

Comment: Арсений, что ты уже попытался сделать сам? Что именно не получилось? Здесь не сайт по решению домашек.

Comment: Решение похожей проблемы уже было представлено -> [stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717303/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-n-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2)

Comment: @Эникейщик Спасибо что соблюдаете правила, но это я делаю для себя и задал вопрос я, потому что мне не было это понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = "У Маши есть рыжая корова"

print([x[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, len(x), 4)])
```

Comment: отличное решение в одну строку, но не думаю что без пояснений автор вопроса поймет как это работает.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin может быть автор вопроса решит, понял он или нет?

Comment: Это фишка питона. 
for i in range(0, len(x), 4)] - это разбивка текста от нуля до за 4 символа до конца
[x[i:i + 4] - бирем этот кусок символов с i по i+4 и пхаем в массив, пока цикл спереди не кончица
Вот вам и разбивка

Comment: @вася Спасибо за ответ, всё сработало

Comment: @SlimRG Тоже спасибо, за объяснение