# Как перемножить списки в Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, списки

Имеется текстовый файл с данным содержанием `"D11i14V17A8n7R11H16r18P18E5h18i18x8O16Y5s13d1X6u4a20C2p2O14J5I11L5K6y4X19n10s17h1E17Q5Z1U1K6U8E8L11n14k6"`. Я написал код который разделяет буквенные значения в один список, цифровые в другой. Как правильно перемножить данные из списка, чтобы в конечном итоге получилось `D * 11 = DDDDDDDDDDD` (Буква D 11 раз). Код ниже:

```
import re
c = []
d = []
result = 0
with open('dest.txt', 'r') as s:
    for line in s:
        line = line.strip()
        lst = re.split('(\d*)', line)

        for i in lst:
            if i.isalpha() == True:
                c.append(i)
            else:
                d.append(i)

for a, b in zip(c, d): 
     result += a*b

print(result)
```

Результат:

```
D:\Python\lib\re.py:212: FutureWarning: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.
  return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-24c875dcd30e> in <module>()
     16 
     17 for a, b in zip(c, d):
---> 18      result += a*b
     19 
     20 print(result)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Comment: Вроде `[a] * b`

Comment: К сожалению такой способ не работает. Ошибка продолжает выходить.

Comment: А какой должен получиться `result` для строки `A2B3` ­— `AABBB`? Почему тогда в начале переменной `result ` присваивается ноль (не пустая строка, не пустой массив, а именно ноль)?)

Comment: Немного переиначил код, но спасибо за подсказку. Действительно надо в result добавить пустую строку. Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [20]: import re

In [21]: task = "D11i14V17A8n7R11H16r18P18E5h18i18x8O16Y5s13d1X6u4a20C2p2O14J5I11L5K6y4X19n10s17h1E17Q5Z1U1K6
    ...: U8E8L11n14k6"

In [22]: numbers, lit = list(re.findall(r'\d+', task)), list(re.findall(r'\D', task))

In [23]: ''.join(int(x) * y for x, y in zip(numbers, lit))
```

Результат:

```
Out[25]: 'DDDDDDDDDDDiiiiiiiiiiiiiiVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVAAAAAAAAnnnnnnnRRRRRRRRRRRHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPEEEEEhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiixxxxxxxxOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOYYYYYsssssssssssssdXXXXXXuuuuaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaCCppOOOOOOOOOOOOOOJJJJJIIIIIIIIIIILLLLLKKKKKKyyyyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXnnnnnnnnnnssssssssssssssssshEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEQQQQQZUKKKKKKUUUUUUUUEEEEEEEELLLLLLLLLLLnnnnnnnnnnnnnnkkkkkk'
```

Comment: Все должно было выводиться в одну строку. Но все равно благодарю за такой вариант.

Comment: @Yamil поправил

Comment: Чем мне Питон нравится, что иногда код написанный независимо разными людьми, практически одинаково выглядит. Моё решение практически такое же, но `re.split()` используется, чтобы  [одним regex обойтись](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/718035/23044)

Comment: @jfs и правда так лучше

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы распаковать файл/обратить [кодирование длин серий (RLE)](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9), удобно использовать `re.split()`, чтобы отделить символы от цифр, и `zip()`, чтобы попарно их обойти:

```
import re
from pathlib import Path 

rle_tokens = iter(re.split(r'(\d+)', Path('rle.txt').read_text()))
decompressed = ''.join([char * int(digits) for char, digits in zip(rle_tokens, rle_tokens)])
print(decompressed)
```

Объяснение [как zip(it, it) работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/377884/23044).

Результат:

```
DDDDDDDDDDDiiiiiiiiiiiiiiVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVAAAAAAAA...
```

Comment: Зачем квадратные скобки в `join()` ?

Comment: @Alban чтобы список создать. Если список (последовательность) не передать, `''.join` изнутри сам список создаёт (лишний раз строки обходит). Строго говоря, это преждевременная оптимизация, так что дело вкуса со скобками или без писать.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так переделал код. Надо было присвоить result пустую строку.

```
import re
c = []
d = []
result = ''
with open('dest.txt', 'r') as s:
    for line in s:
        line = line.strip()
        lst = re.split('(\d+)', line)

        for i in lst:
            if i.isalpha() == True:
                c.append(i)
            else:
                d.append(i)

for a, b in zip(c, d):
    str(a) * int(b)
    result += str(a) * int(b)


print(result)
```

Comment: Ещё замечу, что лучше делать `split` по `\d+`, а не по `\d*`, так как в последнем случае под регулярное выражение подходит пустая строка, а это вроде плохо (у меня, например, warning выдаётся)

Comment: И ещё цикл `for i in lst:` можно заменить на `c = lst[::2], d = lst[1::2]`

Comment: Совершенно верно, лучше использовать \d+ иначе выдается предупреждение, только обозначено оно предупреждением на будущее.