# Не могу понять, почему выводит неправильный ответ

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код ниже должен принимать строку содержащую букву,количество (Пример: a3b4c2e10b1). Должен вывести aaabbbbcceeeeeeeeeeb, но выводит eeeeeeeeeebbbbbbbbbb. Учить я зык только начинаю, поэтому помогите мне, пожалуйста, с моими ошибками.

```
a=input()
p=''
 for item in range(len(a)):
    if a[item].isalpha():
       p=a[item]
    else:
        if item!=len(a)-1:
            if a[item+1].isdigit():
                for i in range(int(a[item])*10+int(a[item+1])):
                    print(p, end='')
        else:
            for i in range(int(item)):
                print(p,end='')
```

Comment: Попробуйте в коде прокомментировать каждую строку, хотя-бы для себя. Так гораздо проще искать ошибки в логике программы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как перемножить списки в Python 3.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718001/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-python-3-x)

Comment: Надеюсь, что разбора моего решения достаточно, чтобы не разбирать ошибки в Вашем варианте. Если нет, пишите, попробую объяснить. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Учитывая, что множители могут иметь не один разряд, ИМХО удобней решать через `re`

```
import re
a = input()
nums = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', a))
alpha = re.split(r'\d+', a)
print(''.join(x * y for x, y in zip(nums, alpha)))
```

#### Вариант с использованием цикла:

```
b = list(input())
letters = []
nums = []

while b:  # Пока список b содержит хоть один элемент
    dig = ''  # Создаем (или обнуляем) переменную которая будет содержать число
    if b[0].isdigit():  # Если первый элемент списка является цифрой...
        while b and b[0].isdigit():  # До тех пор пока b содержит хоть один элемент
                                    # и первым элементом списка будет цифра
                                    # !!! Обратите внимание !!! порядок важен, если операторы поменять местами,
                                    # То python бросит исключение поскольку попытается обратиться к несуществующему
                                    # индексу 0 пустого списка.
            dig += b.pop(0)  # Изымаем первый элемент списка и дописываем его к значению числа множителя
        nums.append(int(dig))  # После чего добавляем получившийся множитель в список множителей
    else:  # Если первый элемент списка b - буква...
        letters.append(b.pop(0))  # Добавляем ее в список букв
    if nums and letters:  # Если в списке букв и множителей накопилось по одному элементу...
        # Изымаем первые элементы через pop и выводим результат без перевода строки
        print(letters.pop(0) * nums.pop(0), end='')
```

Comment: Спасибо, вариант интересный, но к сожалению я такого еще не учил

Comment: @ДмитрийЧеботарев, добавил решение с циклом

Comment: Спасибо большое! Понял все кроме места, где нельзя менять местами, в цикле. Я думал можно перечислять в каком хочешь порядке и как хочешь.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧеботарев, операторы сравнения выполняются слева направо, цикл `while`  в данном случае будет выполняться, до тех пор, пока оба условия верны. Если мы добавили последний элемент списка к переменной `dig` и изъяли его, то список будет пуст, соответственно в нем не будет элемента с индексом 0 и если первым будет стоять условие проверяющее не является ли элемент списка с индексом 0 цифрой, то возникнет ошибка обращения к элементу с несуществующим индексом. А так, он проверяет что, список пуст и на этом успокаивается.

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек

Comment: @ДмитрийЧеботарев, лучшее спасибо - зеленая галочка рядом с ответом :-)))

Comment: @ДмитрийЧеботарев: и не только галочка, а ещё и upvote)