# Time Error на тесте для класса Buffer, который копит элементы и выводит сумму каждых пяти по мере их накопления

Tags: python, алгоритм, производительность

Я сейчас прохожу задания на stepik. Вот ссылка на конкретное задание https://stepik.org/lesson/24461/step/9?discussion=611901&unit=6767

> Реализуйте класс Buffer, который будет накапливать в себе элементы последовательности и выводить сумму пятерок последовательных элементов по мере их накопления.

Программу пишу, все работает на разных тестах... Сайт не принимает задание, пишет Time Error..Работает она вроде быстро, подскажите как что исправить?

```
class Buffer:
    def __init__(self):
         self.buff =[]

    def add(self, *a):

        for i in a:
            self.buff.append(i)
        while len(self.buff) >= 5:
            i = 0
            sum = 0
            while i != 5:
                sum += self.buff[0]
                self.buff.remove(self.buff[0])
                i += 1
            print(sum)

    # print(self.buff)
    def get_current_part(self):

        return self.buff


buf = Buffer()
buf.add(1, 2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
print(buf.get_current_part())  # вернуть [1, 2, 3]
buf.add(4, 5, 6)  # print(15) – вывод суммы первой пятерки элементов
print(buf.get_current_part())
buf.add(7, 8, 9, 10)  # print(40) – вывод суммы второй пятерки элементов
print(buf.get_current_part())
buf.add(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)  # print(5), print(5) – вывод сумм третьей и четвертой пятерки
print(buf.get_current_part())  # вернуть [1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш метод `add()` является квадратичным — `O(len(a)**2)`: `self.buff.remove(self.buff[0])` выполняется за `O(len(self.buf))` время  и при этом эта операция повторяется приблизительно `len(self.buff)` раз. У вас `len(self.buf)` приблизительно равен `len(a)`, поэтому общее время пропорционально квадрату `len(a)`. Подробнее, [посмотрите в конце ответа объяснение, почему квадратичных решений лучше избегать, если ввод не ограничен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596513/23044).

Можно сделать `add()` операцию линейной — `O(len(a))`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

class Buffer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buff = []
        self.bufsize = 5

    def add(self, *a):
        # iterate bufsize items at a time
        for chunk in zip_longest(*[chain(self.buff, a)] * self.bufsize):
            if chunk[-1] is None:  # input is not divisible by bufsize
                break
            print(sum(chunk))
        else:  # all values are summed
            chunk = []
        self.buff[:] = (n for n in chunk if n is not None)  # keep unconsumed part

    def get_current_part(self):
        return self.buff
```

Здесь [`zip(*[iterator]*n)` это идиома по обходу итератора по `n` элементов за раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/377884/23044).

Тест:

```
import io
import contextlib

def test_buf():
    with io.StringIO() as file, contextlib.redirect_stdout(file):
        buf = Buffer()
        assert file.getvalue() == ""
        buf.add(1, 2, 3)
        assert file.getvalue() == ""
        assert buf.get_current_part() == [1, 2, 3]
        buf.add(4, 5, 6)
        assert file.getvalue() == "15\n"
        assert buf.get_current_part() == [6]
        buf.add(7, 8, 9, 10)
        assert file.getvalue() == "15\n40\n"
        assert buf.get_current_part() == []
        buf.add(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        assert file.getvalue() == "15\n40\n5\n5\n"
        assert buf.get_current_part() == [1]
        buf.add(0)
        assert file.getvalue() == "15\n40\n5\n5\n"
        assert buf.get_current_part() == [1, 0]
```

Comment: А зачем нужен `self.buff[:] = filter(None, chunk)`?

Comment: @gil9red:  `self.buff` остаток невыведенный хранит, поэтому в последней (некратной) группе есть None значения в chunk. `filter(None` отсеивает Falsy значения (None, 0, etc).  Если во входе нули хочется сохранять, то лучше `(n for n in chunk if n is not None)` вместо `filter(None, chunk)` использовать.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте:

```
class Buffer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._nums = []

    def add(self, *a):
        part_size = 5

        # Добавить следующую часть последовательности
        self._nums += a

        while len(self._nums) >= part_size:
            # Сумма первой пятерки элементов
            print(sum(self._nums[:part_size]))

            # Удаление первой пятерки элементов
            self._nums = self._nums[part_size:]

    def get_current_part(self):
        # Вернуть сохраненные в текущий момент элементы
        return self._nums
```

Comment: у вас также квадратичный алгоритм: `self._nums[part_size:]` это `O(n)` операция и повторяете вы её `O(n//part_size) = O(n)` раз итого: `O(n*n)`.

Comment: попробуйте: `buf.add(*(1,) * 10**6)` (перенаправив stdout предварительно)